# Most efficient way of authenticating and storing user login info in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know of two ways of storing and authenticating the user login info:

1. Storing the user id in a server side session and then when someone calls to the server check if they have a user session. (Using node client sessions)
2. When the user logins, store a authentication token in the user's table and store the token locally on the users client as well. Then when the user calls to the server they send the authentication token as a header and check if the token is in the user table.

While both of these ways are viable and applicable, I have problems/questions with both of them:

1. I've been told storing the info in session goes against the rest api idea of auto scalability. Is this true and is there a way around it?
2. When storing the authentication key, won't you only be able to store one key/instance per user. What would you do if you wanted to have the same account logged in on two computers or clients (I know I can just create an authentication table, but what if a client loses a token and the authentication token stays forever in the authentication table).

If there are better ways of doing this please bring it up, but I am very confused which direction to move towards. I am gravitating toward the second way, but I still like the first way.

Edit: I have narrowed it down to JWT and my second idea. I don't know which would be better with node.

Answer (score 0):

How about [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/)? They're a variant of the second method you mention and are a recognised industry standard, so you can easily find an implementation for your stack.

You can store the tokens in a key-value store like Redis instead of a relational database, which will be much faster. Redis also supports timing out a key after a while, so expired tokens will disappear automatically. You can also set it up so that each token is invalidated once used, and any request to the API returns a new token for use in the next request, allowing users to continually refresh their token.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using express, you can use [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) for managing your sessions.

Then, you need to add a suitable [session store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores) instead of the default MemoryStore, which is for debug use only, and will not scale to more than one process instance (for the reasons you mentioned in your question).

Fro example, if you are using a PostgreSQL database, you could consider using [connect-pg-simple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-pg-simple). This would store your sessions in your DB, so that your session management does not prevent you from scaling your node.js server. In addition, you can store multiple sessions per user, that will expire (and get automatically erased) based on the maxAge that you configure, thus solving the second problem you mentioned.